# Lumen 5.4 Auth viaRequest $request-input returning null

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

For whatever reason, my AuthServiceProvider has stopped working. It looks like the $request parameter being passed to the closure for viaRequest is not seeing the request input. If I send JSON with a key of "access_token" to any of my endpoints and try and var_dump it in the closure - it only returns null. Here is the code for the boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        var_dump($request->input('access_token'));
    });
}
```

And here is my auth middlewares handle method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {            
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated since I am pulling my hair out right now.

**EDIT** Looks like the issue is with Sentry and their user_context setting be set to true. As soon as I set it to false, the requests come through perfectly

Comment: So it's solved?

Comment: Yes. Should have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be Sentry's user_context setting being set to true. Setting it to false fixed the issue.